# How to print values from an XML as a delimited file

Tags: text-processing, sed, xml

I have a file that contains two XMLs, separated by newlines as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?><ORDERS05><IDOC><EDI_DC40><TABNAM/><DOCNUM>123456</DOCNUM><DIRECT/><IDOCTYP/><STDMES>ORDRSP</STDMES><SNDPOR>SI_GIS-EDI</SNDPOR><SNDPRT>LS</SNDPRT><SNDPRN>0000929674</SNDPRN><RCVPOR>SAP_PI</RCVPOR><RCVPRN>SAP_PI</RCVPRN><CREDAT>20170905</CREDAT><CRETIM>105630</CRETIM><REFINT>17832651</REFINT><REFMES>1</REFMES></EDI_DC40></IDOC></ORDERS05>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?><ORDERS05><IDOC><EDI_DC40><TABNAM/><DOCNUM>12345</DOCNUM><DIRECT/><IDOCTYP/><STDMES>ORDRSP</STDMES><SNDPOR>SI_GIS-EDI</SNDPOR><SNDPRT>LS</SNDPRT><SNDPRN>0000929677</SNDPRN><RCVPOR>SAP_PI</RCVPOR><RCVPRN>SAP_PI</RCVPRN><CREDAT>20170905</CREDAT><CRETIM>105630</CRETIM><REFINT>17832651</REFINT><REFMES>1</REFMES></EDI_DC40></IDOC></ORDERS05>
```

I would like to extract the DOCNUM, MESTYP, SNDPRN values from these tags and store them as a comma separated file with every line starting with "XML". If any of the tags is missing (like MESTYP in the XMLs), they are replaced with just a comma. That is my output would need to be:

```
XML,123456,,0000929674
XML,12345,,0000929677
```

When I tried the below code for extracting just the DOCNUM and SNDPRN values , it worked okay:

```
sed 's/.*<DOCNUM>\(.*\)<\/DOCNUM>.*<SNDPRN>\(.*\)<\/SNDPRN>.*/XML,\1,\2/' input.xml >> output.xml
```

However, I guess because the MESTYP tags are missing in the input.xml file, the output does not seem to work with the code below:

```
sed 's/.*<DOCNUM>\(.*\)<\/DOCNUM>.*<MESTYP>\(.*\)<\/MESTYP>.*<SNDPRN>\(.*\)<\/SNDPRN>.*/XML,\1,\2\3/' input.xml >> output.xml
```

The code above doesn't seem to modify the input.xml in any way. Why is this so? How do i change the above code to add a comma when any of the tags (like MESTYP here) are missing?

Note: XML utilities like XMLlint cannot be used, I'd like to have just the existing code tweaked. Thanks!

Comment: *the existing code*  is bad and should be replaced with other approaches. And why *utilities like XMLlint cannot be used* ? Are you able to install `xmlstarlet`?

Comment: awk/sed will never lead to robust/flexible/general/scalable solution when parsing xml/html

Comment: This is on a work server and unfortunately I cannot install both XMLLint and xmlstarlet. Could you please advise why the existing code is bad and what the better approach with just sed/awk/vanilla bash would be? Another approach I tried was to assign print out the tag values as below, but I wasn't sure how to go over a loop for every new line in the file:  

echo $(sed -n '/DOCNUM/{s/.*<DOCNUM>//;s/<\/DOCNUM.*//;p;}' input.xml),$(sed -n '/SNDPRN/{s/.*<SNDPRN>//;s/<\/SNDPRN.*//;p;}' input.xml)

Comment: of course, I could suggest awk solution, but only for your particular 2 lines (if they won't be changed) just for a single operation

Comment: The xml displayed was only a sample that I could manipulate upon. In actuality, I could have 1000s of lines of similar xmls. And they won't be changed.

Comment: « _This is on a work server and unfortunately I cannot install both XMLLint and xmlstarlet._ » If your system administration team will not install necessary tools as part of a formal Change Request there is something very very wrong indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't miss a chance to install XML/HTML parsers as they would be a proper tools for such data.
As the moment, here's ***awk*** workaround for your particular case:

```
awk -F'[<>]' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if($i~/DOCNUM|MESTYP|SNDPRN/) a[$i]=$(i+1) } 
                print "XML",a["DOCNUM"],a["MESTYP"],a["SNDPRN"] }' OFS=',' your.xml
```

The output:

```
XML,123456,,0000929674
XML,12345,,0000929677
```

Comment: I will try to have the XML parsers installed as per your advice. The code works okay, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
while IFS= read -r xmldoc; do
    printf '%s\n' "$xmldoc" |
    xml sel -t -o 'XML,' \
        -v '//DOCNUM'  -o ',' \
        -v '//MESTYPE' -o ',' \
        -v '//SNDPRN'  -nl
done <file.xml >output.txt
```

This creates `output.txt` as

```
XML,123456,,0000929674
XML,12345,,0000929677
```

It reads each line from the input file `file.xml` and sends it to [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) for processing.  The XMLStarlet invocation will find and output the given XML nodes with commas in-between.